# Progress line in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to create a very simple progressbar for my script. So far I've got this, and it works. However, I cannot get it to be a percentage out of 100. My code is the following and it produces basically a dot for every 5 entries in `@entries`.

```
my $total_entries = @entries; 
my $count = 0; 
my $count_tens = $total_entries/0.2;            
$count_tens = sprintf ('%d',$count_tens);

foreach (@entries){

    # do some stuff #

    for (1 .. $total_entries){              
        if ($count == $count_tens){
            print ".";
            $count = 0;
        }   
    $count++;
    }
}
```

I would like to have something that produces always a fixed amount of dots, regardless of the total number of entries in `@entries`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than rewriting the wheel, you may want to use existing code that has already been written, tested and debugged.

http://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ProgressBar

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, and I am aware of the modules out there. The only issue is I need to keep additional module installations to a minimum as the code is shared and some cannot seem to be getting the hang of installing the modules. Thank you though.

Comment: I accept this as the answer, because amon's doe not work for me in the context outlined above.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say we want 80 dots. Then:

```
my $number_of_dots = 80;
my @items = 0 .. 20; # or something
my $items_per_dot = @items / $number_of_dots;

STDOUT->autoflush(1);  # print everything out immediately

for my $i (0 .. $#items) {
    my $dots = $i / $items_per_dot;
    print "\r", "." x $dots;
    sleep 1; # do something
}
print "\n";
```

Note that we avoid rounding errors by calculating the number of dots per item anew on each iteration. The `\r` will move the cursor to the start of the line, so the existing dots will be overwritten each time. You can easily skip the printing if the `$dots` value doesn't change between iterations.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, but I cannot seem to get it to work without overwriting the line each time. I would like to concatenate the dots to the existing ones?! Does that make sense?

Comment: @Felix_Sim You can maintain a variable `$previous_dots` and then only print dots that are new: `print "." x ($dots - $previous_dots); $previous_dots = $dots`